# jQuery multuple linked sliders?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm trying to find an example of multiple linked sliders similar to [estately's
mortgage calculator](http://www.estately.com/listings/info/115-15-147th-st) (can be found on the right bottom of that page).

I've found [this](http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/#multiple-vertical) example but the sliders aren't linked.
Does anyone have a good example i can use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you don't need a tutorial :D It's pretty easy.

Everytime a slider get moved, you update the other sliders.

Use the `slide` or `change` event and update the other sliders.

For example:

```
$( "#slider1" ).bind( "slide", function(event, ui) {
    $("#slider2").slider({ value: 45 });
    $("#slider3").slider({ value: 30 });
});
```

Just add a slide event for each slider and there you go

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking to bind to one slider's "slide" event, then using whatever variables you need to calculate and set the value of your associated one(s)

**edit**
here's a working example: http://www.jsfiddle.net/sNfBM/

using a rudimentary:

```
    // make another slide change
    $('#master').bind('slide',function(){
        var pct = $('#master').slider('option', 'value') / $('#master').slider('option', 'max');
        $('#eq > span').each(function(i,e){
            var ppct = parseInt($(this).slider('option','max') * pct);
            $(this).slider('option', 'value', ppct);
        });
    });
```